# Error 500 cuando agrego mercadopago en mi sitio PHP : 500 internal server error

Tags: php, mercadopago

tengo ese problema. Cuando intento agregar mercadopago sdk a mi sitio no me deja, sale error 500.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
            include_once('./mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.php');

            $mp = new MP($id, $secret);

            $preference_data = array(
                "items" => array(
                    array(
                        "title" => $name,
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "currency_id" => "VEF",
                        "unit_price" => $price
                    )
                )
            );

            $preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
```

Pero sale error en la ultima línea, en la que se llama al create_preference(). Pues cuando coloco esa línea en comentario corre el sitio normal pero cuando no esta en comentario muestra error 500 y no se que puede ser :( Porfavor ayuda! Gracias!

Comment: verifica el log de apache

Comment: Ya lo revise, no me aparece nada... Al parecer es un tema del curl

Comment: buen día, seguis con error 500? a mi me funcionaba bien hasta hace 5 días, y no puedo encontrar el error. defino tofo como vos y me da error.

Comment: Hola, si a mi me paso igual. Habia solucionado y despues me salió error, entonces busqué la manera con el sdk nuevo de mercadopago y creando los botones y con jquery llegando a ellos... Algo todo anormal pero funcionó :P

Comment: Tu creas el boton y con el <script ...></script> y le das a una ID y luego ocultas el botón. Despues con jQuery llegas al botón, asi hice yo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya resolví! Erra que faltaba forzar el: `$price` cambiarlo por `(float) $price`
Hice eso y se resolvió.

Comment: Agrega una explicación de que realiza lo que comentas en tu respuesta y sea de ayuda a la comunidad, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Quedo claro no? Cambiar $price por (float) $price

Comment: y que realiza ahora con : (float) $price  ?

Comment: No sé realmente, fuerza a que el valor de $price sea un float creo... Lo ví en un tema similar a este y probé su solución...

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta para que te des una idea de como realizar respuestas, por ejemplo la respuesta que realizas solo mencionas que con eso se resuelve pero no que es lo que hace el cambio.

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentación](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php) se puede ver que en la preferencia tienes que definir varios valores:

```
        "title" => "Test",       //string
        "quantity" => 1,         //integer
        "currency_id" => "USD",  //string
        "unit_price" => 10.4     //float
```

en el caso de `"unit_price"` estas definiendo `$price` que no contiene un valor tipo `float`, lo cual es incorrecto.

Por lo tanto puedes realizar un [**casting**](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php)

```
"unit_price" => (float) $price
```

o incluso para obtener el valor flotante de la variable usar **[floatval()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php)**:

```
"unit_price" => floatval($price)
```